# Setting id to objects on JavaFX Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to draw rectangle, line etc. on canvas with `GraphicsContext`.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20,20,10,10);
rect.setId("myRect");
gc.draw(rect);
```

Is there something like this in JavaFX? Or is there a way to access drawn canvas objects?

Comment: Make a snapshot and draw the resulting image... Or simply use the properties of the rectangle to draw a rectangle on the canvas that looks like the rectangle node you created...

Comment: Please check your tags, as you've tagged multiple versions of javafx.

Comment: thanks fabian. I try to use the rectangle node for drawing on canvas. But then i can't drag this rectangle on canvas with mouse event action. So i thought that the  rectangle on canvas must be same as the rectangle node.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know you can't draw `Rectangle`s directly on a canvas - `Rectangle` is a JavaFX node, but the Canvas API is much lower level and only takes very basic drawing commands. For example, for drawing your rectangle, it would be:

```
GraphicsContext gc = theCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.fillRect(20,20,10,10);
```

This however doesn't let you manipulate the rectangle any further. what I do is create a custom class `DrawableRectangle` (for example) with a method draw:

```
public class DrawableRectangle extends Rectangle {

    Canvas theCanvas;

    public DrawableRectangle(Rectangle r, Canvas c){
        super(r.getX(),r.getY(),r.getWidth(),r.getHeight());
        this.theCanvas = c;
    }
    public DrawableRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h, Canvas c){
        super(x,y,w,h);
        this.theCanvas = c;
    }

    public void draw(){
        GraphicsContext gc = theCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("black"));
        gc.fillRect(getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
    }

}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
    GraphicsContext gc = theCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    DrawableRectangle rect = new DrawableRectangle(10,10,20,20, theCanvas);

    // Draw it:
    rect.draw();

    // You can then manipulate it:
    rect.setY(40);
    rect.setHeight(60);

    // You need to draw it again to see the changes:
    // First clear the canvas:
    gc.clearRect(0,0,theCanvas.getWidth(),theCanvas.getHeight());
    // Then draw it:
    rect.draw();
```

(I can't guarantee this is the best method, but it worked well for me. If you want to draw different shapes this way you should make an interface Drawable to abstract it.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to dragging that rectangle with mouse and this rectangle must be stored with it's id in my project..How do it on canvas? or İf I don't use canvas, what will be my disadvantage?  I will need to more shapes later, not only a rectangle.

Comment: Sorry, I only see your comment now, don't know if I can still help. You can manipulate the rectangle (ex. drag and drop) by adding event handlers to the DrawableRectangle class. You should probably use higher level api's than canvas though, such as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/package-summary.html